# Data entered in an MYSLQ db does not automatically display once Saved

Tags: python, pyqt4, mysql-python

I am writing a program using python 3.4 to allow a user to enter their Name and Surname and once they hit save the data should save in the db an display on screen. The Data saves to the db fine( I know this because every time I close the program and run it the previous entry displays). My problem here is that when I enter the data and hit save, it does not automatically display on the screen in the tabelView widget. I used QT designer 4 to create the widget and my database table only contains two columns, Full_Name and Surname. How can I get my entry to display immediately after hitting the save button?

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from Nametest import *
from PyQt4 import QtSql, QtGui
import mysql.connector
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="shotokan", db="name")
cursor=conn.cursor()


def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
    db.setHostName('localhost')
    db.setDatabaseName('name')
    db.setUserName('root')
    db.setPassword('shotokan')
    db.open()
    print (db.lastError().text())
    return True
class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
       self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)
       self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
       self.model.setTable("fullname")
       self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
       self.model.select()
       self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)


       QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()' ),self.InsertRecords)



     def InsertRecords(self):

         cursor.execute( """INSERT INTO fullname (First_Name, Surname)VALUES('%s','%s')""" %(self.ui.lineEdit.text(),self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()))
    conn.commit()



 if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
      if not createConnection():
             sys.exit(1)
      myapp = MyForm()
      myapp.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is an image of my Widget:

[image: Save name and Surname to DB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use 2 technologies to do the same task, if you have used QSqlTableModel to display the information then use that model to do the insert:

```py
class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("fullname")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.InsertRecords)

    def InsertRecords(self):
        db = self.model.database()
        db.transaction()
        record = self.model.record()
        record.setValue("First_Name", self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        record.setValue("Surname", self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
        if self.model.insertRecord(-1, record):
            print("successful insertion")
            self.model.submitAll()
        else:
            db.rollback()
```

<sub>Note: Do not use concatenation to create a query since your application is susceptible to SQL Injection.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your help.Much appreciated. This fixed my issue.